# Using SQL Server on docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I want to run SQL server locally via docker. I'm using these two commands, first this one:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

And then the second one to actually run the server:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=mypassword" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Next step would be connecting to it using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but it's not possible because docker image shuts down with code 255 maximum 20 seconds after starting it. I'm unsure how to fix this issue.

Edit

If I connect within 5-10 seconds MSSMS connects successfully, but then reports and error that host closed connection. So for reasons unknown docker image just shuts down on its own.

Comment: `mypassword` is most certainly not a secure password and so the set-up would have failure. *Hopefully* you chose a more "secure" password in your real attempt?

Comment: @ThomA Yes. But it's local and for testing purposes so it can unironically be mypassword in this example.

Comment: Use [`docker logs <container-name>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) to get more details on the error.

Comment: If you *did* use `mypassword` then, as I stated, that's why the server isn't starting; setup failed due to the use of an insecure password.

Comment: @ThomA error is quite unusual. It says that password needs to be at least 8 characters long, but it is 8 characters long. But I have managed to found the error. It doesn't recognize character `$`, which probably made password shorter. I have replaced it and now it runs.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bash "thing", @AaronBertrand , as the dollar (`$`) character is a special character. The `$` character would be seen as the start of a variable name, and then [variable substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCyMB.png) occurs, and likely resulting in truncation.

Comment: As a side note, if you *did* want a password to contain a dollar (`$`) character, you would need to escape it. `"MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyPa\$\$w0rd"`

Comment: "There are actually explicit rules where Docker won't let SQL Server start if you use a lazy password" it's not *docker*.  The contents of that SQL Server image are the things fussing about the password.  I don't know if other images like mysql / postgresql care or I just don't set stupid passwords when I use them

Comment: Don't people just [read the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) any more? In the requirements, _A strong system administrator (SA) password: At least 8 characters including uppercase, lowercase letters, base-10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols._